# SwiftUI - Presenting a View on top of the current View from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a project that at some point it receives a `notification`. When that happens, I need to show a `View`. I am not able to catch `notification` from any `View` so I am looking for a way to change to control it from outside of `View` structs. After the `View`'s purpose is done, I need to dismiss it where the app left off. Think like the native behaviour when there is an active call.

I thought I could use `sheet` however I could not find any way to trigger it for every `View` that could be active when the `notifications` come. Or maybe trying to extend native `View` class would work  but again, no luck finding a tutorial.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update your model based on notification. There is not necessary to define .sheet (modal view) everywhere in your view hierarchy. Doing it in root view should be enough.

To demonstrate that (copy - paste - run) I create small project where I mimic notification with SwiftUI Toggle.

```
import SwiftUI

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var show = false
}
struct SubView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    var tag: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: SubView(tag: tag + 1).environmentObject(model)) {
                Text("subview \(tag)")
            }
            if tag == 2 {
                Toggle(isOn: $model.show) {
                    Text("toggle")
                }.padding()
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("subview \(tag)")
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SubView(tag: 0).environmentObject(model)
        }.sheet(isPresented: $model.show) {
            Text("sheet")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

with the result

[image]

Comment: Well I thought about this before. However I did not want to carry `Enviroment Object` to each `View` for just in case there could be an notification. Also it should work after `CallKit` notif is being answered. Can we do it from `window.rootViewController` somehow? @user3441734

Comment: @Faruk why? i did it only because the toggle !! you don't need to do it this way. the sheet is ONLY on root view. that is the demonstration about!

Comment: @Faruk in real app define the modal in root View and use .onReceive to make it active if notification was published.

Comment: I see. You are keeping the `sheet` at the top most view. So I will have that sheet on my `MainView` and I wouldn't need to carry it as `envobject`. I understand now, thanks. @user3441734

Comment: @Faruk yes, you got it!!

Comment: @Faruk the notification must be exposed ONLY to your root view, where you define .sheet

Comment: I got clearly got it. Lastly, I am doing this for to mimic native active call page and the native only works when the device locked. The question is, when the device is unlocked but it is in the background, how can I make this sheet to show up first? @user3441734

Comment: @Faruk You can also achieve this without environment variable with a closure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70870750/swiftui-modify-state-var-from-remote-closure